# Format To Display the Thousand Part of a Double Value

Tags: java, formatting

For example; I have the next *Double* value: `Double number = 53149000;`

And I want to display it like this, with a format: `53,149`

Is this possible...?

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.format method after dividing your value by 1000

```
double number = 53149000;
System.out.println(String.format("%,.0f", number/1000));
```

Comment: That can be shortened to `System.out.printf("%,.0f%n", number / 1000);`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the `DecimalFormat` object to achieve that. For example:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###");
System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(number/1000));
```

It prints `53,149` as expected.

I hope it helps.